# Merge CSV file with Bash

Tags: bash, csv, merge

I have 2 csv file like this :

```
name;num;value1
name1;1;1
name1;2;10
name2;1;5
```

and

```
name;num;value2
name1;2;8
name2;2;6
name1;1;7
```

i want to merge this 2 CSV like this

```
name;num;value1;value2
name1;1;1;7
name1;2;10;8
name2;1;5;6
```

the 2 csv have name and num but not in the same order. How i can add the value2 column in the fisrt file in the right order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=b[$1]=$NF;next} 
         {print $0, (a[$1,$2])?a[$1,$2]:b[$1]}' file2 file1
name;num;value1;value2
name1;1;1;7
name1;2;10;8
name2;1;5;6
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you explain your code, I dont know much about awk and i like to understand what my code is doing

Comment: I suggest reading some starting awk tutorial. This answer is using 2 associative arrays but some basics of awk will give you a good understanding. We can only write limited text in comments.